# Naming a database table with the current date through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking to run a mysql_query() that allows me to create a new table within a database and name it according to the current date and time.

Example: Create a table named 2012-01-09-03-00-00, or something along those lines.

I know that this is not an optimal way of doing things, but ultimately I'm going to take the data on this table and dump it into a bigger database.

I've tried the code:

```
<?php
$date = date('YmdHis', time()-(3600*5));
$exportSQL = "CREATE TABLE $date(
FirstName varchar(15)
)";
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_query($exportSQL) or die (mysql_error());
echo "Table created!";
?>
```

But this has been to no good. Please Help and thanks in advance.

EDIT: THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED. THE CODE WORKING SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
<?php
$date = date('YmdHis', time()-(3600*5));
$exportSQL = "CREATE TABLE `$date`(
FirstName varchar(15)
)";
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_query($exportSQL) or die (mysql_error());
echo "Table created!";
?>
```

Comment: Will the database be normalized after you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Except that it is **very** weird design, if you want to name table in such a way - place its name in square brackets, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [2012-01-09 12:20:15.010] (your columns)
```

that means that you should have the name of the table *BEFORE* composing the query, **OR** you have to use dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE['+
  CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR)+N'-'+
  CAST(DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR)+N'-'+
  CAST(DATEPART(day, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR)+N'-'+
  CAST(DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR)+N'-'+
  CAST(DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR)+N'-'+
  CAST(DATEPART(second, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR)+
  N'] (FirstName varchar(15))'

EXEC(@sql)
```

The presented syntax is for **sql server**, so due to the sql compliance you can replace square brackets with double quotes and use proper date functions, but the **approach** left just the same

Comment: do you mean backtics (`) I don't think MySQL uses square brackets like MSSQL and others do. Ditto for Dynamic SQL

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, i read with mistake mysql as mssql. Little bit commented an answer at its end

Comment: @M_M: **only** SQL Server uses the strange brackets as a replacement for the standard double quotes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've seen them in access too (though access barely qualifies as a DB...) either way I should have qualified that statement better.

Comment: @M_M Ok, lets say that "only microsoft uses there strange brackets" 8-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Why, I thought that was inherited from Sybase with the entire T-SQL stuff of the time.

Comment: @OlegDok: One other thing thing that would likely be different is the dynamic scripting part: how you construct it and how you invoke it. But yes, the approach would basically be the same, I guess.

Comment: @M_M This actually worked! The solution to implement was backticks before the variable $date. This way the table doesn't have to be named before running the script and the script will name it dynamically. Thank you all for your help!